# How do I add multidimensional tables using Pander?

Tags: r, pander

I'm trying to add a 3D table to a .docx report using Pander, specifically via Live report Generation:

```
A=sample(LETTERS[1:5],100, rep=T)
b=sample(letters[1:2],100, rep=T)
numbers=sample(1:3,100, rep=T)

tab=table(A,b,numbers)
tab1=ftable(addmargins(tab))

tempReport=Pandoc$new(title="Pander and ftable", format="docx")

tempReport$add.paragraph("### table: tab")
tempReport$add(tab)

tempReport$add.paragraph("### table: tab1")
tempReport$add(tab1)

tempReport$export()
```

However, it cannot seem to handle the multidimensional table:

> Error in data.frame(txt = cells, width = cols.width, justify = justify) : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 3

Is there a way to get around this?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Thank you @daroczig: using the development build I have now got the 3D table appearing! 
The column/row names have quotation marks "" around them, but other than that, all seems well.

Comment: This is a bug in `pander`, which I will try to fix in the next few days.

Comment: `pander` was not able to deal with 3D tables so far, but I've just pushed a quick workaround, please test the [development build](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/compare/06646da23d...cbc4cd7776) installing `pander` from GitHub (probably with `devtools`): http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#installation